# Intesection of Ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let P denote prime ideals,an $A_1,A_2$ ideals, i need to know how can i describe

$\{P | A_1\subset P\}\cup\{P | A_2\subset P\}$

I mean it is equal to

$\{P | A_1\cap A_2\subset P\}$

I think not, maybe is

$\{P | A_1.A_2\subset P\}$

Anyone can give an idea?

Comment: Since $P$ is prime, those two sets are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Both guesses are correct.

As a hint on how to prove the first:
$$\{P \ \text{prime} \ | \ A_1 \subseteq P\} \cup \{P \ \text{prime} \ | \ A_2 \subseteq P\} = \{P \ \text{prime} \ | \ A_1 \cap A_2 \subseteq P\}$$
One direction is easy and one direction is hard.  For the hard direction you'll need to use something called the "prime avoidance lemma".

Comment: Thanks very much i have seen that and prove now :)

Comment: After you've figured out how to prove that the first guess is correct, then prove the following statement: For $P$ prime, $A_1 \cap A_2 \subseteq P$ if and only if $A_1A_2 \subseteq P$.  That will show you that your second guess is correct as well.  For this the inclusion $A_1A_2 \subseteq A_1 \cap A_2$ will be useful.

Comment: Ok, thanks i have seen that to, but with the first guess works for what i need to do